# Achievement is not appearing in my timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

When I'm creating an achievement using the command line like this:

curl -d "access_token=[app-access-token]" https://graph.facebook.com/[my-fb-id]/achievements?achievement=http://beta-app.tetrisstars.com/www/resources/fb_achievements/tetrisstars_beta/SingleSolo-mission_1.html

it returns something like this: {"id":"2488619866064"}

So that seems fine, right? Yet, the achievement does not appear in my timeline.

When I create an achievement for our internal test app:

curl -d "access_token=[app-access-token]" https://graph.facebook.com/[my-fb-id]/achievements?achievement=http://ec2-50-16-187-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com/tetris_stars/www/resources/fb_achievements/ts_devtest/SingleSolo-mission_1.html

I do see the achievement in my timeline. Also when I enter the achievement URL in the object debugger, everything seems to be fine.

I did run into a problem earlier, where initially it didn't want to register my achievements, saying all the time: {"error":{"message":"(#3502) Object at achievement URL is not of type game.achievement","type":"OAuthException"}} even though I was using exactly the same method to register as for our other apps.

Only after a lot of searching did I figure out I had to set my App Domain in the app settings, something I didn't need to do for the other apps like the ts_devtest app above. A better error message could have saved me considerable time.

Apparently somehow Facebook is treating the two apps differently. But gives no clue how, why or what. Anything else I need to do to make the achievements appear in the timeline? Our high-scores appear there fine, it's just the achievements that are not appearing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK, I figured something out. When I removed the app and added it again, passing by the permission dialog, after that the achievements did appear in the timeline. But then that means there's something wrong at FB as we didn't change the permissions. And the high-scores were getting through, which AFAIK are part of the same 'publis_actions' permission.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I inspect the users achievements using graph API, I see that they are there, but one interesting field called "importance" is set to zero. I don't know if this affects anything, but achievements are not shown.